# React pass props between sibling components with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I'm new to React and creating small app with REST Api to get some practice! So, when I clicking to pokeBox, in sider must be displaying details information about selected pokemon.
I attaching screenshot , how it looks now.

[image: screenshoot]

But I have no idea how I have to get constant with Pokemon.url.
It's my structure:

1. Wrapper (Parrent Component);

   1.1. PokemonsList (Children);

   1.1.1 GridCards (Children of PokemonsList)

1.2. About (Children)

So, I must get pokemon.url from GridCards and how I understanding, save in parrent component.
But, how is it was with functional component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the hooks you can set a state in the parent component:

`const [selectedPokemon, setSelectedPokemon] = useState()`

and trigger a function when a new `pokeBox` is clicked in which to call `setSelectedPokemon(pokemon.url)`.

In this way, you just have to pass `selectedPokemon` to the child component `About` in which you can render what you want based on the `selectedPokemon` value.

Comment: How i passing `setSelectedPokemon` ?
As another props?

Comment: @ValeriySamoilov If your pokeBox container is a button you can write something like this: `<Pokemon onClickPoke={(url) => setSelectedPokemon(url)} />` and in the child component `Pokemon` use `<button onClick={() => props.onClickPoke(url)}>...</button>`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put a piece of state in the parent component that you can pass to the about component (here you will save the data of the pokemon you want to display). Then you make a function to set data to the state you've just created and pass it to the PokemonList component so you can call that function when you click the name of the pokemon.

In wrapper:

```
this.state = {
    selectedPokemon: {} // Pass this state to about comp as props
}

// Pass this function to pokemonList comp as props
setPokemon = (pokemon) => this.setState({ selectedPokemon: pokemon });
```

Comment: Will this spelling be correct, if I using functional component?



`const [SelectedPokemon, setSelectedPokemon] = useState([]);

setSelectedPokemon=(pokemon) => ([SelectedPokemon, pokemon])
`

Comment: setPokemon = (pokemon) => setSelectedPokemon(pokemon);